# window.open returns null in IE8 Protected Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to catch the return value of window.open(), but it is returning null/undefined. This happens when IE8 Protected mode is turned ON. Is there any altenative to get the window.open() returned object without disabling the protected Mode in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to perform one of the things Protected Mode is specifically designed to stop...

From Microsoft -- [open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Opening a new window from an application (other than the Internet Explorer process) may result in a null return value. This restriction occurs because Internet Explorer runs in protected mode, by default. One facet of protected mode prevents applications from having privileged access to Internet Explorer when that access spans process boundaries. Opening a new window by using this method generates a new process. For more information about protected mode, see 
>   [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb250462(v=vs.85).aspx). This commonly occurs for applications that host the WebBrowser control.

If you're looking for a way to perform similar, then we'll need to know exactly what your doing and how your attempting to use window.open.

Most likely though, that would be a programming-specific problem, which would be off-topic for SU.