# window.open returns null in IE Protected Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to catch the return value of window.open(), but it is returning null. This happens when IE8 Protected mode is turned ON. Is there any alternative to get the window.open() returned object without disabling the protected Mode in IE?

I saw one similar post on stack overflow  but did not get any solution from that link.
[window.open returns null in IE8 Protected Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417203/window-open-returns-null-in-ie8-protected-mode)

Could anyone help me to find out the solution for this issue?. I want the window.open object to hold the child window object and close it on some particular condition.